# Integrating Facebook users with our app using laravel 5.2 socialite

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, laravel, migration

Actually, i was following instructions from http://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-socialite-facebook-login.html#.V2yhIbjJvIU

Step on which i got stuck is

**Add following fields to the migration:**

```
Schema::table('social_accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->string('provider_user_id');
    $table->string('provider');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Run the migrations**

> php artisan migrate:refresh

error on running this command :

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>
> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table
>   'social
>   _acco   unts' already exists (SQL: create table `social_accounts` (`id` int un signe   d not null auto_increment primary key,
>   `created_at` timestamp null, `u pdate   d_at` timestamp null) default
>   character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ ci)
>
> [PDOException]
>
> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table
>   'social
>   _acco   unts' already exists

and following is my error on localhost after clicking on fblogin.

> QueryException in Connection.php line 713: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
>   found: 1054 Unknown column 'provider' in 'where clause' (SQL: select *
>   from `social_accounts` where `provider` = facebook and
>   `provider_user_id` = 1130902766955428 limit 1)

**My migration file :**

```
  <?php

  use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
  use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

  class CreateSocialAccountsTable extends Migration
 {
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('social_accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
    }); 

    Schema::table('social_accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->string('provider_user_id');
    $table->string('provider');
    $table->timestamps();
});


}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('social_accounts');
}
 }
```

**My controller file:**

```
 <?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use Illuminate\Http\Request;

   use App\Http\Requests;

   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

    use App\SocialAccountService;

    use Socialite;

   class SocialAuthController extends Controller
  {
  public function redirect()
 {
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();   
}   

public function callback(SocialAccountService $service)
{


  $user = $service->createOrGetUser(Socialite::driver('facebook')->user());

    auth()->login($user);

    return redirect()->to('/home');
             }
        }
```

**files in my app folder:**

SocialAccount.php

```
       <?php

        namespace App;

        use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

        class SocialAccount extends Model
         {
     protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'provider_user_id', 'provider'];

      public function user()
   {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
     }
```

*SocialAccountservice.php*

```
           <?php

             namespace App;

              use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\User as ProviderUser;

              class SocialAccountService
             {
          public function createOrGetUser(ProviderUser $providerUser)
             {
           $account = SocialAccount::whereProvider('facebook')
        ->whereProviderUserId($providerUser->getId())
        ->first();

    if ($account) {
        return $account->user();
    } else {

        $account = new SocialAccount([
            'provider_user_id' => $providerUser->getId(),
            'provider' => 'facebook'
        ]);

        $user = User::whereEmail($providerUser->getEmail())->first();

        if (!$user) {

            $user = User::create([
                'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                'name' => $providerUser->getName(),
            ]);
        }

        $account->user()->associate($user);
        $account->save();

        return $user;

    }

}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

step 1:remove the socialite references from the config/app.php

step 2: run composer update

step 3:then run composer  dump-autoload

step 4:then add socialite references to config/app.php

step 5:Lastly, run composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 1):

There is already a table named 'social_accounts' in database. First delete that table & then try to run migration.

Comment: sorry, but its not working. Same error is displayed.